# insmod: ERROR: could not load module: Permission denied

Tags: linux, centos, linux-device-driver

I am trying to build and load a simple kernel module. I am able to build the module but am unable to load it.

**skm.c**

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

static int __init skm_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit skm_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Good Bye");
}

module_init(skm_init);
module_exit(skm_exit);
```

**Makefile**

```
KERNEL_SOURCE := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)

obj-m += skm.o

all:
    make -C $(KERNEL_SOURCE) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C $(KERNEL_SOURCE) M=$(PWD) clean
```

The insmod command fails with the 'Permission Denied' error.

```
[user1@localhost LinuxKernelModules]$ make clean
make -C /lib/modules/3.10.0-514.21.1.el7.x86_64/build M=/home/user1/projects/LinuxKernelModules clean
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-514.21.1.el7.x86_64'
  CLEAN   /home/user1/projects/LinuxKernelModules/.tmp_versions
  CLEAN   /home/user1/projects/LinuxKernelModules/Module.symvers
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-514.21.1.el7.x86_64'
[user1@localhost LinuxKernelModules]$ make
make -C /lib/modules/3.10.0-514.21.1.el7.x86_64/build M=/home/user1/projects/LinuxKernelModules modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-514.21.1.el7.x86_64'
  CC [M]  /home/user1/projects/LinuxKernelModules/skm.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /home/user1/projects/LinuxKernelModules/skm.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/user1/projects/LinuxKernelModules/skm.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-514.21.1.el7.x86_64'
[user1@localhost LinuxKernelModules]$ sudo insmod skm.ko
[sudo] password for user1: 
insmod: ERROR: could not load module skm.ko: Permission denied
```

The directory and the object files have write and execute permissions. And user1 has the same permissions as root.

```
[user1@localhost LinuxKernelModules]$ ls -al
total 296
drwxr--r--.  3 user1 user1  4096 Jun  6 16:52 .
drwxrwxrwx. 11 user1 user1  4096 Jun  5 18:42 ..
-rwxr--r--.  1 user1 user1   831 Jun  2 11:58 fcdm.c
-rwxr--r--.  1 user1 user1   811 Jun  6 16:28 Makefile
-rw-rw-r--.  1 user1 user1    58 Jun  6 16:52 modules.order
-rw-rw-r--.  1 user1 user1     0 Jun  6 16:52 Module.symvers
-rwxr--r--.  1 user1 user1  2146 Jun  2 17:53 scdm.c
-rwxr--r--.  1 user1 user1   397 Jun  6 16:52 skm.c
-rwxr--r--.  1 user1 user1 94872 Jun  6 16:52 skm.ko
-rw-rw-r--.  1 user1 user1   279 Jun  6 16:52 .skm.ko.cmd
-rw-rw-r--.  1 user1 user1   736 Jun  6 16:52 skm.mod.c
-rwxr--r--.  1 user1 user1 52848 Jun  6 16:52 skm.mod.o
-rw-rw-r--.  1 user1 user1 25181 Jun  6 16:52 .skm.mod.o.cmd
-rwxr--r--.  1 user1 user1 43560 Jun  6 16:52 skm.o
-rw-rw-r--.  1 user1 user1 25121 Jun  6 16:52 .skm.o.cmd
drwxrwxr-x.  2 user1 user1  4096 Jun  6 16:52 .tmp_versions
```

I am running this on a CentOS 7 computer which has the kernel headers installed.
I was able to build and load the module with the same source code and build configuration on a CentOS 6 computer running an older kernel(2.6.x).

**Solution**:
The error is because the `$HOME` directory resides on an NFS server to which the computer is not given root access, as described in this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10681). Loading the module from the `/tmp` directory works just fine.

Comment: Did you try to turn SELinux off and check if the module would load successfully without it?

Comment: @DmitriChubarov Thanks. I disabled it permanently and rebooted, but the  error persists.

Comment: Try to run `make ... modules_install; depmod -a`, and check again. It might be the modules there are signed and you didn't do that.

Comment: Check `dmesg` for an error message. Anything there?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The problem was related to NFS access. I have updated the information in my question.